# How long does Windows Explorer remember folder customisations for in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I've noticed that if I right-click in a folder, go to "View By" and then add custom columns from within the "More..." menu, I'll go back into that same folder several months later and my custom columns have disappeared. Is there a hard limit for the amount of time that Explorer will remember customisations for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These customisations are stored in two ways:

- The folder type ("General", "Music", etc.) is stored in a hidden/system `desktop.ini` file within the folder.
- Other folder customisations, including view and column settings, are stored in the user registry, in a location colloquially known as "ShellBags".

There is technically no hard *time* limit on these customisations, but there are a few scenarios where they might be lost:

- There is a limit to the *number* of saved customisations. Apparently this defaults to 5000 in Windows 7. [You could have a go at increasing this number.](https://superuser.com/a/1104654/117590)
- Since these settings technically do store a list of folders you've customised, some "privacy" tools think removing them is a good idea. If you run any such tools (e.g. CCleaner - not recommended in any case), they might be clearing your settings.
- Some registry "cleaning" tools (please don't use them...) might decide to remove the relevant entries.

Comment: Geeze, I forgot I asked that question in your link.